# Sticky menu inside a grid doesn't work in Semantic UI

Tags: semantic-ui

I would like to have a sticky menu on my page but I'm unable to make it work.

This is my current setup:

```
<div class="ui basic segment">
    <div class="ui grid">
        <div class="three wide column">
            <div class="ui sticky">
                <menu-home-vertical></menu-home-vertical>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="thirteen wide column" id="homeContent">
            <div ui-view="main"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

And I initialize the sticky menu using:

```
$('.ui.sticky').sticky({context : '#homeContent'});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was in no way related to Semantic UI, but more to the fact that I'm developing a single page application.

Everything on the website is loaded dynamically when it's needed so, most of the time, when the various Angular controller are initialized the content is not in place yet causing the view to have a 0 pixels height and thus the Semantic UI sticky module is initialized with a 0 pixels height context.

To solve this issue I'm simply refreshing the sticky menu on every scroll event. This makes sure that the sticky menu is working correctly.

Answer (score 0):

@siannone If "the Semantic UI sticky module is initialized with a 0 pixels height context", does

```
$('.ui.sticky').sticky();
```

work? This makes it refer to itself.

Answer (score 0):

I had similar problem. The content of "ui sticky" div was loaded dynamically. The solution for me was calling

```
$('.ui.sticky').sticky({context : '#homeContent'});
```

Each time when the content of the sticky div changed.

```
$.ajax({
    url: '',
    data: '',
    success: function(content) {
        $('#sticky_div_id').empty();
        $('#sticky_div_id').append(content);

        $('.ui.sticky').sticky({context : '#homeContent'});
    }
});
```